# Traer el valor de una lista si esta en ella, python

Tags: python

una manita por favor, tengo un objeto que me almacena varias listas y quiero validar si un serial se encuentra en ese objeto y si esta que me traiga la posición [0] es  decir la caja en la que se encuentra.

```
base = [('CAJA1','2631'),('CAJA1','2632'),('CAJA2','2634'),('CAJA2','2635'),('CAJA3','2636'),('CAJA3','2627')]

serial = '2634'
for row in base:
    if serial in base:
        res = "El serial se encunetra en la caja: "+ Aca no se como indicar la caja
```

Comment: Podés hacer row[1] == serial para saber si el primer item de la tupla es la cadena que buscas (recuerda hacer la comparación con el serial convertido en cadena, ya que una cadena nunca será igual a un número) y si eso devuelve True, hacer row[0].

Comment: Bonus: errores de concepto. Tu condicional con in se pone a buscar el serial en base, o sea la lista de creaste inicialmente. Pero incluso si lo cambiases a row, devolvería falso, ya que son tuplas de dos cadenas y no hay numeros allí.

Comment: Hola, @DanteS. gracias por tu comentario, ya corregi lo de el serial, en  si seria un string por asi decirlo, ya que esto es un aparte del codigo, en el momento si me hace la busqueda, solo que me pidieron como algo adicional es indicar en que caja esta el serial.  entiendo que el con el "in" toma todo y hace la busqueda y devuelve si se encuentra, pero no se como hacer los otro, o tendria que cmabiar la forma en que lo busco?,

Answer (score 1):

Hago una aclaración: tienes una lista la cual contiene varias tuplas.

Sabiendo esto, tienes que saber que cada tupla es una posición en la lista.

Primero debes ir recorriendo toda la lista, sabiendo el tamaño de la misma utilizando la función len(), luego evaluas si el serial se encuentra en esa tupla haciendo la validación.

El código seria de la siguiente manera:

```py
base = [('CAJA1','2631'),('CAJA1','2632'),('CAJA2','2634'),('CAJA2','2635'),('CAJA3','2636'),('CAJA3','2627')]

serial = "2634"

for row in range(len(base)):
    if base[row][1] == serial:
        print("El serial se encuentra en la {}".format(base[row][0]))
        break
```

Espero haberte ayudado